# a gem for handling accounts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just wondering my question maybe a little vague but perhaps there's a more elegant solution.

Imagine you have a team-based application and multiple users shares one account.

One team will have one account id, so everytime you fetch data for a particular user, you always fetch their data according to their account id, like so:

```
articles = Wiki.find_all_by_account_id(1)
files = File.find_all_by_account_id(1)
tasks = Task.find_all_by_account(1)
```

Basically every time you pull data out of a db should always be for a particular account

This is how I handle it right now but perhaps just wondering if there's any elegant solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just set the conditions in the Account model when creating the relationship to articles, files and tasks and then you just do `@account.articles, @account.files ....`

Since you are always gonna need the account, you can use it as a method for filtering the other models

Comment: But how do i create articles, files and associate it with account id when i start creating them? I want to be able to set it only in one location rather than always passing the current user's account id to every record creation.

Comment: you can do `@account.articles.create(...)` and that will automatically will set your the account_id in your models